# Add Portablekanban task from Outlook

Tags: .net, vba, outlook, com

We use portablekanban (pk) as a project management tool. It can be downloaded from https://dmitryivanov.net/. Great tool but doesn't support Outlook yet. PK has a quick task bar plugin so any special formatted string can be added as a task. this plugin's source can also be downloaded from developer's website. So I write a macro to export a message in a special format that quick task bar plugin accepts. But I haven't find a way to automate (triger quick task bar window, add string then enter key maybe?) creating tasks. is there a way to get the plugin window from outlook and run the string?

A workaround maybe, create tasks in a temp txt file on a specified folder. write a pk plugin (name it folder plugin) to read that file and parse tasks then run add task commands inside pk. but in that way I will have to manually run the folder plugin every X minutes and its a hassle. Any suggestions to better automate it?

sorry for mistakes as its not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend contacting the plug-in developer and asking for any public API instead. You can call add-in's code from VBA, see [Walkthrough: Calling Code in a VSTO Add-in from VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Also you may try to use [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592(v=vs.85).aspx) for entering the required information to the UI controls.

Comment: Thanks.. MAA seems interesting. I asked for public api. fingers crossed :)